# cakephp hasMany gives empty data set

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a "Motor" model:

```
class Motor extends AppModel
{
   var $name = 'Motor';
   var $hasMany = array(
                       'MotorPictures' => array(
                          'className'       => 'MotorPicture',
                          'foreignKey'      => 'motor_id',
                          'dependent'       => true
                          )
                   );
}
```

Along with a MotorPicture model:

```
class MotorPicture extends AppModel
{
   var $name = 'MotorPicture';
   var $actsAs = array(
      'FileUpload.FileUpload' => array
      (
         'uploadDir' => 'img/motors',
         'required' => true
      )
   );
```

}

Here is the database:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `motors`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `motors` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `make` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `year` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `notes` text NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `edited` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `motors`
--

INSERT INTO `motors` (`id`, `make`, `model`, `year`, `notes`, `created`, `edited`)
VALUES (0000000001, 'Audi', 'S4', 2000, 'This is a freaking sweet car.', '2011-01-11 21:04:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `motor_pictures`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `motor_pictures` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `motor_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `size` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `motor_pictures`
--

INSERT INTO `motor_pictures` (`id`, `motor_id`, `name`, `type`, `size`, `created`, `modified`)
VALUES (1, 1, 'kitten.JPG', 'image/jpeg', 80518, '2011-01-12 20:13:55', '2011-01-12 20:13:55'),
(2, 1, 'kitten-1.JPG', 'image/jpeg', 80518, '2011-01-12 20:15:28', '2011-01-12 20:15:28');
```

When I bring up my view and print_r($motor) the output is such:

```
 Array ( [Motor] => Array ( [id] => 0000000001 [make] => Audi [model] => S4 [year] => 2000 [notes] => This is a freaking sweet car. [created] => 2011-01-11 21:04:00 [edited] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ) [MotorPictures] => Array ( ) )
```

As you can see (at the end of that long thing), the "MotorPictures" array is empty, even though the SELECT that the hasMany relationship enforces returns 2 results in the debug output.

Can anyone point me towards the thing I am doing wrong or just plain omitting?

Thanks!

Comment: Publish the code of your controller's find operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out my key and foreign key did not ***exactly*** match.  One was an int (10) and the other was an int (11).  Once I made one match the other in my database, it all started working.

Answer (score 0):

I see in your Motor model `Moter.id = 0000000001` and in your `MotorPicture` you have `MotorPicture.moder_id=1`.

`0000000001` is not the same as `1`

Answer (score 0):

Oftentimes this sort of thing is caused by a too-restrictive recursion setting. Try setting $Motor->recursive = 1 in your controller before you call $Motor->find.